# Python: Comparing all elements of two arrays and modifying 2nd array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

New to Python, and have been learning about arrays. I am stuck with a simple enough problem and need a solution. I have two arrays:

```
a = [2.0, 5.1, 6.2, 7.9, 23.0]     # always increasing
b = [5.1, 5.5, 5.7, 6.2, 00.0]     # also always increasing
```

and I want the resultant array to be:

```
c = [0.0, 5.1, 6.2, 0.0, 0.0]      # 5.5, 5.7, 00.0 from 'b' were dropped and rearranged such that position of equivalent elements as in 'a' are maintained
```

I have compared both 'a' & 'b' using Numpy as in:

```
y = np.isclose(a, b)
print y
# [False False False False False]
```

(Alternately,) I also tried something like this, which isn't the right way (I think):

```
c = np.zeros(len(a))
for i in range (len(a)):
    for j in range (len(a)):
        err = abs(a[i]-b[j])
        if err == 0.0 or err < abs(1):
            print (err, a[i], b[j], i, j)
        else:
            print (err, a[i], b[j], i, j)
```

How do I proceed from here towards obtaining 'c'?

Comment: Try `y = np.isclose(a, b, atol=0.05)`.

Comment: It isn't affecting the result. Putting `atol=0.5` gives `[False  True  True False False]` which is `c` bool-wise.

Comment: Do I simply copy element values from `a` at position of `True` values? Or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Do equivalent values have to be at equal indices? Or would `a=[5,6,7]; b=[0,0,5]` give `c=[5,0,0]`? (Your comment in your 2nd code snippet is not clear to me.)

Comment: Yes equal values at equal indices, but since the values are in ascending order (always increasing), sorting will be easier. 2nd snippet is an alternate way.

Comment: You write that array b is "also always increasing", but its last value is `00.0`.

Comment: Intentionally put. To be considered as bad-data/junk values which can be ignored while following 'always increasing' rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These solutions work even when the arrays are of different size.

**Simple version**

```
c = []

for i in a:
    if any(np.isclose(i, b)):
        c.append(i)
    else:
        c.append(0.0)
```

**Numpy version**

```
aa = np.tile(a, (len(b), 1))
bb = np.tile(b, (len(a), 1))
cc = np.isclose(aa, bb.T)
np.any(cc, 0)
c = np.zeros(shape=a.shape)
result = np.where(np.any(cc, 0), a, c)
```

---

*Explained:*

I will be doing matrix comparison here. First you expand the arrays into matrices. Lengths are exchanged, which creates matrices having equal size of one dimension:

```
aa = np.tile(a, (len(b), 1))
bb = np.tile(b, (len(a), 1))
```

They look like this:

```
# aa
array([[  2. ,   5.1,   6.2,   7.9,  23. ],
       [  2. ,   5.1,   6.2,   7.9,  23. ],
       [  2. ,   5.1,   6.2,   7.9,  23. ],
       [  2. ,   5.1,   6.2,   7.9,  23. ],
       [  2. ,   5.1,   6.2,   7.9,  23. ]])

# bb
array([[ 5.1,  5.5,  5.7,  6.2,  0. ],
       [ 5.1,  5.5,  5.7,  6.2,  0. ],
       [ 5.1,  5.5,  5.7,  6.2,  0. ],
       [ 5.1,  5.5,  5.7,  6.2,  0. ],
       [ 5.1,  5.5,  5.7,  6.2,  0. ]])
```

Then compare them. Note that bb is transposed:

```
cc = np.isclose(aa, bb.T)
```

And you get:

```
array([[False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

You can aggregate this by axis 0:

```
np.any(cc, 0)
```

which returns

```
array([False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Now create array c:

```
c = np.zeros(shape=a.shape)
```

And select appropriate value, either from a or c:

```
np.where(np.any(cc, 0), a, c)
```

And the result:

```
array([ 0. ,  5.1,  6.2,  0. ,  0. ])
```

Comment: I think this is what the OP wants. But he added a comment now saying that there may be trailing junk values at the end of the `b` array which must be ignored. So one would need to trim that array before using it, or adapt the algorithm. (Applies to all current answers, I think.)

Comment: Yes, I've added a comment about the assumption. The remainder can be np.appended if necessary.

Comment: Very thorough explanation I must say. Only thing is, if one used numpy to generate an empty matrix of zeroes (say) `c`, won't `np.append` throw errors, instead of using `c[i] = b[j]`.

Comment: I've edited a fix for different array sizes (just exchanged len(a) and len(b)). Basically - all that you now have to do is decide where bad data starts and remove it so it will not interfere with comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Try to better explain what your program should do in a more general way.  Only giving arrays a, b and c does not tell what it should do.  It is as if someone said "If A=5 and B=7, write a program so that C=20".

From what you tried, I'd guess that the task is "each element of c should be equal to the corresponding element of a if its value is near (difference of 0.5 or less) to the corresponding value in b.  It should be zero if not."

Also, do you really need to use numpy?  Try using only loops and list methods.  You may also have a look at "Generator expressions and list comprehensions"

Finally, your title says "(...) and modifying 2nd array".  There should not be a third array named c.  The result should appear in a modified version of array b.

---

Edited: if the specification was **really** this, then the code could be

```
a = [2.0, 5.1, 6.2, 7.9, 23.0]
b = [5.1, 5.5, 5.7, 6.2, 0.0]
c = []
for x,y in zip(a,b): c.append( x if abs(x-y)<=0.5 else 0.0 )
print c
```

Which gives the following answer

```
[0.0, 5.1, 6.2, 0.0, 0.0]
```

BTW, if this is for a course, you could still get a bad grade for not following the specification ("...and modifying the 2nd array").

Comment: You guessed the task right. I tried alternately using loops instead of Numpy (see 2nd snippet). And the modifying 2nd array is what I need to do, but I would settle for third array `c` as it helps in keeping things simple for the time being.

Comment: Hint: if you are beginning in python, you should stick to the base language (i.e. "Language reference" and "Library reference" in the python documentation).  Don't try using external libraries (e.g. Numpy) yet.

Comment: It isn't for a course btw, I am a data science enthusiast and encountered this problem while working with different data sets. The arrays actually represent columns of a much larger data set.

Comment: You could also modify `b` directly using array indices:  `for i in range(len(a)): 
  b[i] = a[i] if abs(a[i]-b[i])<=0.5 else 0.0`

Comment: I didn't really think it was for a course: people who do that usually paste the homework assignment word for word.  I wrote that to emphasize the fact that the first step when writing a program (whatever language you program in) starts by having a clear idea of the task to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

With `np.isclose` you already create an array where the "closest" elements are `True`. So you can use this result to set all other elements to zero.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2.0, 5.1, 6.2, 7.9, 23.0])     # always increasing
b = np.array([5.1, 5.5, 5.7, 6.2, 00.0])     # also always increasing
a[~np.isclose(a,b, atol=0.5)] = 0
a
```

this returns `array([ 0. ,  5.1,  6.2,  0. ,  0. ])`.

But notice you want to set all elements that are not close, so you need to invert (`~`) the result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to keep elements of `a` that are also in `b`.

A pure linear time python solution :

```
c=zeros_like(a)

j=0
n=len(c)
for i in range(n):
    while j<n and b[j]<a[i]-.1 : j+=1
    if j==n : break
    if abs(a[i]-b[j])<.1 : c[i]=a[i]
```

And a numpy solution for exact matching:

`a*in1d(a,b)`.

[`in1d(a,b)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) indicates the places of  elements of `a` that are in `b` : `in1d(a,b)` is `[False, True, True, False, False]`

Since `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`  ,  `a*in1d(a,b)` is  `[ 0., 5.1, 6.2, 0. , 0. ]` . Since `in1d` sorts  `a` and `b`, it is a n ln n complexity algorithm, but generally faster. if approximative equality is required, a solution can be rounding the arrays first (`np.round(a,1)`)

Comment: I arrived with a solution pretty similar to yours using nested for loops only

Comment: Yes, But it's a quadratic algorithm, it don't use the fact that arrays are sorted. It will be inefficient on big arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is the alternate way I was able to obtain the required arrangement for c.

```
import numpy as np

a = [2.0, 5.1, 6.2, 7.9, 23.0]  # always increasing
b = [5.1, 5.5, 5.7, 6.2, 00.0]  # also always increasing
c = np.zeros(len(a))

for i in range (len(a)):
    for j in range (len(a)):
        err = abs(a[i]-b[j])
        if err == 0.0 or err < abs(0.1):
            c[i] = b[j]

print c
#[ 0.   5.1  6.2  0.   0. ]
```

Comment: Thanks. Now your aim is more clear. I give more efficient solutions in my post.

Comment: In the `if`statement, `abs(0.1)` could be written without the `abs` function (abs(0.1) is 0.1).  Also if `err == 0.0`, that also implies that `err < 0.1`, so the first condition is redundant.  You could just write `if err < 0.1:`.

Comment: `abs(0.1)` is redundant in this case but when there are close enough values, `err` might be negative in some cases. So `err == 0` and `err < abs(0.1)` would be required. I tried using different set of values just for testing the code and this statement worked like a charm.